# How to use JavaScript Linkify script with _target="blank"?

Tags: javascript, string, url, hyperlink

Anyone know how to make this JavaScript Linkify script use _target="blank" to open links in a new window?

https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-linkify

Answer (score 2):

looks like you can pass it options:

```
default_options = {
  callback: function( text, href ) {
    return href ? '<a href="' + href + '" title="' + href + '">' + text + '</a>' : text;
  }
```

is in the js file.

Pass it a different callback.

From the comments, it is called thus:

```
linkify( text [, options ] );
```

I am guessing you are calling it this way:

```
var linkified = linkify(someText);
```

Call it this way instead:

```
var linkified = linkify(someText,{
     callback: function( text, href ) {
          return href ? '<a href="' + href + '" title="' + href + '" target="_blank">' + text + '</a>' : text;
}});
```

Or if you have to call it multiple times, save the second parameter in a variable and pass it the variable instead.

It's often instructive to just read the unminified source code. This one is only about a hundred lines and is fairly easy to follow. I think if you give it an honest try, you will be surprised how much you can discover for yourself.